# Docker Compose Image Failing

Tags: node.js, redis, docker, docker-compose

I am learning about Dockerfiles and docker-compose. When I manually run the Dockerfiles and create the containers they all work as they should however by triggering the build and deploy using a docker-compose.yml script the subscribe container stops working.

The process that works successfully is:

```
docker build -t cu/broker:1.0.0 broker/
docker run -d --name broker -p 6379:6379 cu/broker:1.0.0
docker build -t cu/subscriber:1.0.0 subscriber/
docker run -d --name subscriber --link broker:db cu/subscriber:1.0.0
docker build -t cu/publisher:1.0.0 publisher/
docker run --name publisher --link broker:db -ti cu/publisher:1.0.0
```

After running these commands I have two running containers and an interactive console where I can send individual publish commands to the redis server.

Rather than adding each script to this question together with a folder structure I have written a shell script that resets everything and generates the correct structures and files.

When I trigger the docker-compose.yml script it completes successfully but only the broker container is running, the other two terminate as soon as they start. I don't understand why and even with the --verbose flag I get no useful information to help debug this. This is the command I use to run the script.

```
docker-compose --verbose up -d
```

And here is the shell script config.sh that builds the folder and file structure.

```
#!/bin/sh
# builds the folder structures and dockerfiles

echo "STOPPING RUNNING CONTAINERS"
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
echo "DELETING ALL CONTAINERS"
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
echo "DELETING ALL IMAGES"
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
docker ps
docker images

if [ -d docker ]; then
    echo "DELETING EXISTING FILES AND DIRECTORIES"
    rm -rf docker
fi

echo "CREATING DIRECTORIES AND FILES"
mkdir docker
cd docker
echo -e "broker:" >> docker-compose.yml
echo -e "  build: broker/" >> docker-compose.yml
echo -e "  ports:" >> docker-compose.yml
echo -e "    - \"6379:6379\"\n" >> docker-compose.yml
echo -e "subscriber:" >> docker-compose.yml
echo -e "  build: subscriber/" >> docker-compose.yml
echo -e "  links:" >> docker-compose.yml
echo -e "    - \"broker:db\"\n" >> docker-compose.yml
echo -e "publisher:" >> docker-compose.yml
echo -e "  build: publisher/" >> docker-compose.yml
echo -e "  links:" >> docker-compose.yml
echo -e "    - \"broker:db\"\n" >> docker-compose.yml

mkdir broker
cd broker

echo "CREATING BROKER DOCKERFILE"
touch Dockerfile
echo -e "FROM redis:3.0.3" >> Dockerfile
echo -e  "RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y\n" >> Dockerfile
cd ..
mkdir publisher
cd publisher

echo "CREATING PUBLISHER DOCKERFILE"
touch Dockerfile
echo -e "FROM ubuntu:14.04" >> Dockerfile
echo -e  "RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y" >> Dockerfile
echo -e  "RUN apt-get install -y redis-server && service redis-server stop" >> Dockerfile
echo -e  "CMD redis-cli -h $DB_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR\n" >> Dockerfile
cd ..
mkdir subscriber
cd subscriber

echo "CREATING SUBSCRIBER DOCKERFILE"
touch Dockerfile
echo -e "FROM node:0.12.7" >> Dockerfile
echo -e "RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y" >> Dockerfile
echo -e "RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils tree wget nano" >> Dockerfile
echo -e "WORKDIR /home" >> Dockerfile
echo -e "ADD index.js /home/index.js" >> Dockerfile
echo -e "RUN npm install ioredis" >> Dockerfile
echo -e "CMD ["node", "/home/index.js"]\n" >> Dockerfile

echo "CREATING JAVASCRIPT FILE"
echo -e "var redis = require('ioredis');" >> index.js
echo -e "var port = process.env.DB_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT;" >> index.js
echo -e "var ip = process.env.DB_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR;\n" >> index.js
echo -e "client = redis.createClient(port, ip, {});\n" >> index.js
echo -e "console.log('REDIS PORT: '+port);" >> index.js
echo -e "console.log('REDIS IP:   '+ip);" >> index.js
echo -e "console.log('subscribed to "test" channel');\n" >> index.js
echo -e "client.subscribe('test');\n" >> index.js
echo -e "client.on('message', function(channel, message) {" >> index.js
echo -e "    console.log('MESSAGE RECEIVED');" >> index.js
echo -e "    console.log('CHANNEL: '+channel);" >> index.js
echo -e "    console.log('MESSAGE: '+message);" >> index.js
echo -e "});\n" >> index.js
cd ..
```

Comment: Could you share your docker-compose.yml file (or fig.yml)?

Comment: I have added the docker-compose.yml code to the shell script as well as reproducing it below, cheers: broker:
  build: broker/
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"

subscriber:
  build: subscriber/
  links:
    - "broker:db"

publisher:
  build: publisher/
  links:
    - "broker:db"

Comment: How are those two getting terminated? With an error? What happens when you for e.g. `docker-compose run --rm subscriber`? What versions of Compose and Docker are you using?

Comment: I ran your script and the subscriber service is exiting with some node.js error.  
`Docker 1.7.1` and `Compose 1.3.3`

Comment: Docker version1.7.0, docker-compose version 1.3.3. Output from the docker-compose command here: https://gist.github.com/marktyers/7de25ccaed9c5dbecdd9 If I run docker-compose run subscriber I get the error /bin/sh: 1: [node,: not found I think the error here is I didn't escape the quotes!

Comment: Your sh script generates `CMD [node, /home/index.js]` and it should `CMD ["node", "/home/index.js"]` as it goes JSON in the end. Update to Docker 1.7.1 as 1.7.0 gave me some weird entrypoint errors recently.